# Create Downloader Library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to implement [Downloader Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files#Preparing)

And I encounter severals difficulties :

At the step 3 :

> Specify an app/Library name such as "Google Play License Library" and
>   "Google Play Downloader Library", choose Minimum SDK level, then
>   select Finish.

i have no such options as "Google Play License Library" and

> "Google Play Downloader Library"

[image]

At step 5, there is no such `Properties Tab` or `Library repository` :

[image]

For these reasons, i'm stuck at creating my Downloader Library

Comment: did you try the command line way of doing it? fyi step 3 is just saying "give it .a name, and here are 2 example names"

Answer (score 0):

As [Blundell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56793607/create-downloader-library-in-android-studio#comment100142384_56793607) stated in his comment, the first issue you have is only that they are suggesting a name as an example, not pointing you to a specific setting.

As to your second issue with step 5, YOU ARE on the `Properties Tab` already! Take a look here:

[image]

Comment: according to google APK Expansion files guideline... https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Preparing
`Select the Properties tab and in Library Repository, enter the library from the <sdk>/extras/google/ directory (play_licensing/ for the License Verification Library or play_apk_expansion/downloader_library/ for the Downloader Library).`

as we can see from your captured image, there is no Library Repository  also..